# If else condition combine && and || in one row statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Thank you for your time, i create some if else statement in checkbox to display result, can i combine && and || condition in one statement? for example

```
if (radioMale && chestPain && (leftArm || bothArm || jaw || throat)) {
highPossibilityOfHeartDisease = true;
}
```

User have to tick radioMale && chest pain && can tick either leftArm, bothArm, jaw or throat (one or more) to return true for highPossibilityOfHeartDisease. Is the code above valid? need some help here.

Comment: The above code won't even compile, because `both arm` is not a valid variable name.  But yes, you may string together any number of terms in an `if` statement with `&&` and/or `||`.

Comment: *Can i combine && and || condition in one statement?* -- Yes. Try it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that must be a typo. it should be bothArm and it is actually one of the checkbox if that what you means. btw thank you sir, so i can proceed with the statement above right?

Comment: @NicholasK thank u

Comment: There is nothing wrong .This condition seems dangerous. How many branches are there in  conditions .It's similar to  X,Y,Z truth table , were Z has again nested truth table .Think about it :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can combine && and || in a `if...else` statement. See it logically before considering programmatic side.

`true AND true AND true AND (true OR false OR false)` the condition inside brackets will be verified and set as one resulted Boolean that may be `true` or `false` according to the condition.

Then the resulting `booleans` will be verified linearly as normal.

You can read some articles explaining maths of boolean expressions, for example:

[The Mathematics of Boolean Algebra: From StanFord University](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boolalg-math/)

[Boolean Expressions](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/26)

[Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)